# Hibernate and C3P0 Issue: MySQLNonTransientConnectionException, Too many connections

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, jdbc, c3p0

I got following exception while using c3p0 with hibernate.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor413.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor407.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

This is my HibernateUtil class (I named it as **SessionFactoryBuilder**)

```
public class SessionFactoryBuilder
{
    private static SessionFactoryBuilder instance;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private SessionFactoryBuilder()
    {
        buildConfig();
        System.out.println("hehehehe");
    }

    private static void buildConfig()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactoryBuilder getInstance()
    {
         if(instance == null) 
         {
            instance = new SessionFactoryBuilder();

         }
      return instance;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }  

}
```

Finally , This is my **hibernate.cfg.xml** file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myglukose</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">********</property>
    <mapping resource="beans/Reminder.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="beans/StressType.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="beans/Medication.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Update**

Below is my database implementation class, which is used by `Service` classes via an interface. This class uses **SessionFactoryBuilder**

```
public class StressTypeDAOImpl implements StressTypeDAOInterface{

    private static final SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = SessionFactoryBuilder.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Session openCurrentSession() {
        Session session=sessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public Transaction openTransaction(Session session) {
        Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
        return transaction;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StressType> getAllStressTypes(Session session) {
        List<StressType> list=(List<StressType>)session.createQuery("from StressType").list();
        return list;
    }

}
```

This is my service class,

```
public class StressTypeService {

    private static StressTypeDAOInterface stressTypeDAOInterface;

    public StressTypeService(){
        stressTypeDAOInterface=new StressTypeDAOImpl();
    }

    public Session getSession(){
        Session session=stressTypeDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        return session;
    }

    public Transaction getTransaction(Session session){
        Transaction transaction=stressTypeDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
        return transaction;
    }    

    public List<StressType> getAllStressTypes(){
        Session session=stressTypeDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction=null;

        List<StressType> list=new ArrayList<StressType>();
        try{
            transaction=stressTypeDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            list=stressTypeDAOInterface.getAllStressTypes(session);
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }    

}
```

Have any ideas about this exception ?

Comment: Where are you using `sessionFactory`? The code where you use it to open a `Session`!

Comment: How do you use Session? Do you ever call Session.close ?

Comment: I will post them in a moment

Comment: @dsp_user : I updated my post .

Comment: @rD.- I updated my post .

Comment: make sure you will close all opened sessions

Comment: All I see is stressTypeDAOInterface.openCurrentSession() but we still don't know whether you're using openSession() or getCurrentSession(). BTW, you should always rollback your transactions in the catch clause. Anyways, try to add  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> to your config file.

Comment: @dsp_user: I am confused. I have posted everything I am using, I have nothing else to post

Comment: Where is the code for openCurrentSession? Also, try to add that line from my last comment to your config file.

Comment: @dsp_user: FYI, the `StressTypeDAOImpl` has the method `openCurrentSession` which is a method of `StressTypeDAOImpl`. The `openCurrentSession()` method's code is `Session session=sessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory().openSession();`

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Just add that line to your code and see if it helps.

Comment: @dsp_user: What that code line you mentioned does please?

Comment: It enables the session per request pattern. Also , make sure that you rollback your transactions.

Comment: @dsp_user: Yes sure. Is it also safe for `Servlets` which multiple users use at "once" ? Servlets are multithreaded

Comment: Yes, it's safe. Servlets (web containers actually), by default, create a new thread for every request, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @dsp_user: OK, Thanks. Any way to "re generate" the problem if there is any? This is an issue from time to time, to generate we had to fire methods for nearly an hour.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: So maybe can you add the code of the servlet ?

Comment: Did you see more that one "hehehehe" in your logs ? Your singleton is not thread safe but I don't think that's an issue.